# Fastest way of comparing the visitor's IP against a list of range IPs

Tags: php, ip

Let me explain what I would liek to do by giving you an example. Let's assume that we would like to
block ( disable or hide) some of our website scripts to users coming from a specific country
I can get the list of IPs of that country from [here](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block.php#blocklist). which gives me ip ranges in the form
aa.bb.cc.0/33
kk.ss.yy.0/24
etc

However I am looking for the fastest way of comparing the visitor's ip againts that list in PHP.
Should i store that list in a file? or the ips have to be stored in a db?

If i use the deny command of .htaccess I have totally blocked the user from visiting any of our website. therefor I have to do it in PHP where i have more flexibilities. 
What i did was to store those range of ips in a file and every time comparing the user's ip against those in the file. but I am under an impression that it is not a very best idea. Please let me know what and how would be the fastest way. thanks

Comment: Why use PHP for this when it can be done with proper server configuration?

Comment: If you want fast concurrent lookup, it's going to be hard to get with plain files.

Comment: @raina77ow the reason i don't prefer doing it in server configuration: 1-I want to make decision based on that in my code. i.e. using it in if-else block of php code to disable some function or enable some others 2- My files are hosted in a shared server, where i dont have full control over parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you must use PHP, then store the list of blocked IP ranges in a database. This is going to be one of the fastest ways to lookup this information, instead of reading textfiles or generating hashmaps from static PHP code (thats a pain to update too). For added speed in your lookups, use indexes properly on your fields and use caching, as its likely the same ip address will look at several pages on your site.

Generate your database table and use 5 columns for the different parts of the IP. This will need to be done monthly or whenever you want to update your list. This can be done using a scripting language of your choice and using cron or something like that.

```
blocked_tbl:
classA   classB   classC    min    max
------   -------  ------   ----- ------
214       101       99       1     255
178       22        45       1     255
...       ...       ...     ...    ...
```

Then you can compare the website visitors IP address to that range, like so:
(split up the ip address in PHP to 4 parts using substr method or explode, 
so that you have $ipA, $ipB, $ipC and $ipD)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM blocked_tbl WHERE
blocked_tbl.classA = $ipA AND
blocked_tbl.classB = $ipB AND
blocked_tbl.classC = $ipC AND
(blocked_tbl.min <= $ipD AND blocked_tbl.max >= $ipD)
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is to store the list of IPs in a database, make the IP column as primary key, and check the occurence of the user IP in the table.

Another way (without database) is to create an hash table of IPs and check in O(1) the occurence of the user IP.

obviously you have to network-mask your IP before checking...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's already answered on [Match IPv4 address given IP range/mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421613/match-ipv4-address-given-ip-range-mask)

As to how to store them, I would not set up a database just for that.  Maybe a flat text file that you read into an array?  If you have a DB already, yes, use it!