# How to allow local IP addresses range and redirect if not using PHP instead of .htaccess

Tags: php, redirect, ip-address, local, lan

I’m trying to redirect all traffic from outside of the local network to a page like **notallowed.php**.

There’s no possibility of using **.htaccess** so I’m trying to do this with PHP, but I’m not sure how I can use a wildcard function on all addresses that begin with `192`.

I started out with something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "192.*.*.*") {
    redirect('noallowed.php');
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match IPv4 address given IP range/mask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421613/match-ipv4-address-given-ip-range-mask)

Comment: Compare the 3 first digits of the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a regular expression to check the string begins with `192`:

```
<?php
if (!preg_match('/^192/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    header('Location: notallowed.php');
    exit;
}
```

I’m also sending a `403` status code to be RESTful.

Comment: regular expression overhead would make this slow, compared to other options.

Comment: It’s not the most complicated of regular expressions, and won’t be any slower than exploding the string and checking components.

Comment: This worked fantastically! I have used it many more times since then.

Comment: Glad to hear, @user3191748 :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$ip_array = explode(".", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($ip_array[0]!="192") 
    redirect(noallowed.php);
```

Or substr() version:

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,3)!="192")
    redirect(noallowed.php);
```

Comment: i suspect `substr()` would be faster

Comment: Maybe. Little difference in this case, anyway. ;) Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826797/php-listexplode-vs-substrstrpos-what-is-more-efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || 
      (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '192.') !== 0)) {
    header('Location: /notallowed.php');
}
```